# Transfer All Custom Field Data From Custom Post Type to User Accounts - Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

## Current Situation

I currently have a custom post type. This custom post type has numerous custom fields. There are many posts of this type, all with the custom fields filled out.

Currently, there is ONE POST of this custom post type that corresponds to each author on the blog. No author has more than one of these posts. The method in which it corresponds is simple, they are the author of their own post.

I used the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to set up and manage my custom fields, and I plan to continue doing that.

### What I Want to Do

Instead of having these custom fields entered in each author's corresponding post, I would like them to be listed directly in their user meta. I can set up the custom fields easily in there using Advanced Custom Fields, even give them the same names and ids.

The the tricky part would be transferring all this data over. I COULD do it manually, but it would take ages. There is a lot of data to deal with.

Can anyone think of a way to automate this? It might be something as simple as renaming an entire table in the database. I have no idea, I don't know much about mysql databases.

#### WHY I want to do this, for those interested

Originally I just needed a way to list a bunch of people, and have a bunch of information about them listed on a page. It was not immediately clear to me that these people were all going to be USERS on the site, so at the time it made sense to just make a custom post type, and just enter each person into that with all their meta data.

But then they all became users on the site, and also authors with their own blog posts. And now I need to be able to query meta data about them FROM a blog post. But I can't figure out any way to do that, since their meta data isn't directly connected to their user account. It would appear that it would just be way easier (and more properly done) to tie all that data directly to their account.

## Alternate Solution? Might be easier

There could be another way to make this work too. If someone can figure out a way to tie that custom post type post directly to its author, to the extent that you could somehow query it from anywhere as long as you knew which author you were querying, that would work and actually be better.

Possible ways to do that (these are just ideas) could include:
-Manually adding the custom post ID to a custom author meta field, so that you could get the ID of the corresponding post from the author's meta (not ideal, since I would have to enter this manually for every new author)
-That was actually my only idea. I thought of somehow using the username and hoping you can mess with that until you get the corresponding custom post... But there is no way to do that I think without tons of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the excellent [Posts 2 Posts plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/). In the official [Wiki](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki) you can find a specific topic that seems to fit your needs: it's called [Posts 2 Users](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Posts-2-Users). I hope this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.